# Can you show/hide series in sunburst diagrams?

Tags: highcharts, sunburst-diagram

Can you use selectable series with a sunburst chart the same way you can use series in an x-range chart? In the x-range chart, series can be selected/deselected (shown/hidden). Can you do something similar in the sunburst chart? Somehow group the data points?

Example of shown/hidden series in x-range chart: http://jsfiddle.net/02Lqotd7/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'xrange'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts X-range'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        categories: ['Prototyping', 'Development', 'Testing'],
        reversed: true
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Project 1',
        // pointPadding: 0,
        // groupPadding: 0,
        pointWidth: 20,
        data: [{
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 21),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
            y: 0,
            partialFill: 0.25
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 5),
            y: 1
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 8),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
            y: 2
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 19),
            y: 1
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 10),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 23),
            y: 2
        }],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true
        }
    },{
        name: 'Project 2',
        // pointPadding: 0,
        // groupPadding: 0,
        pointWidth: 20,
        data: [{
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 21),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
            y: 0,
            partialFill: 0.25
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 5),
            y: 1
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 8),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
            y: 2
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 19),
            y: 1
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 10),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 23),
            y: 2
        }],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }]

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is only one series in `sunburst` chart type, so to hide/show the part of the graph you need to hide/show points. However, this functionality is not supported by default and needs some customization.

The simplest solution is to use `setVisible` method from `pie` series type and internal `legendType: 'point'` option. Next, hide unnecessary legend items in `afterGetAllItems` event.

```
var H = Highcharts;

H.seriesTypes.sunburst.prototype.pointClass.prototype.setVisible = H.seriesTypes.pie.prototype.pointClass.prototype.setVisible

H.addEvent(H.Legend, 'afterGetAllItems', function(e) {
    e.allItems.splice(1, 1);
    e.allItems.splice(2, 1);
});
```

At the end it remains to handle point `legendItemClick` event - you can use point `update` method to set `value: null` for hidden points:

```
    point: {
        events: {
            legendItemClick: function() {
                this.series.points.forEach(function(el) {
                    if (el.color === this.color) {
                        el.update({
                            oldValue: el.value ? el.value : el.oldValue,
                            value: el.value ? null : el.oldValue
                        }, false);
                    }
                }, this);

                this.series.chart.redraw();
            }
        }
    }
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8cLp17of/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update